# Kafka server contains messages but consumer cannot receive any

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Using a producer I entered some messages inside Kafka server which is running on localhost. Zookeeper is also on localhost. I have used `ConsumerGroupExample` as given [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example).

However, the consumer does not seem to receive any message! the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` script can pull out all those messages, but the code cannot. What is wrong? The Consumer code is exactly as it is given on that page.

```
zookeeper="localhost:2181", group id = "test-a", topic = "test".
```

This is the same topic on which I published messages. Here's code for the producer:

```
package test;

import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;
import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;

public class KakfaProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        prop.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        prop.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(prop);
        Producer<String, String> producer = new<String, String> Producer(producerConfig);
        Task t = new Task(producer);
        Thread newThread = new Thread(t);
        newThread.start();
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    Producer<String, String> producer;

    public Task(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public void run() {
        long num = 1;
        while (true) {
            String topic = "test";
            KeyedMessage<String, String> message = new<String, String> KeyedMessage(topic, "Hello Test message " + num);
            producer.send(message);
            synchronized (this) {
                num++;
            }
            if (num % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Total messages sent by Thread-" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually see only producer code here. Are you sure you added proper code?

Comment: I avoided putting consumer code, as it is exactly as given at the link I provided in the problem description

Comment: Ok so from what I see your main thread just finishes earlier than anything happens. Add like `Thread.sleep` or just don't use another thread for producing/consuming and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried consumer with only one thread. Still it doesn't work. Weird thing is, when I take count of items available in iterator by `it.size()` it gives me a proper size. But when I use `it.isEmpty()`, it gives me true!

Comment: if you still have issue then close your consumer console and test. I think you have same group for your topic so your consumer console will consume it.

Comment: @GauravMishra: I don't have any console consumer running.

Comment: @Shades88: could you please update post with consumer code. then I may be able to help you.

Comment: or it is same as provided in above link in your post

Comment: are you able to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `group.id` to something else and test.

When you used `kafka-console-conumser.sh` to test your consumer, it consumed data from the topic and changed an offset.  That's why your Consumer code couldn't consume with the same `group.id`.

Also, when you change your `group.id`, add to your Consumer :

```java
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
```

This will make sure that your new consumer group consumes data from the beginning.

Your consumer didn't receive any data :

1. You already used the same group.id to consume before, and it has a new offset. It will consume only when there is new data in your Broker. (Change the `group.id` and test again.)
2. Try `auto.offset.reset=earliest`. The consumer will read messages from the beginning, and you can use this for testing your consumer.  There are also ways to read from a certain offset. `seek()`, `seekToBeginning()`, and `seekToEnd()`.